# Changing 'src' on A-asset does not update material

Tags: aframe

I'm using A-frame 0.8.2 and don't get behaviour I expect. When I change the source of my asset, it will not refresh on things that use this source. For example:

```
<a-scene>
<a-assets>
    <img id="myPicture" src="myPicture.jpg">
<a-assets>

<a-sky id="sky" src="#myPicture"></a-sky>

</a-scene>

   JS: $("#sky")[0].setAttribute("src", "myPicture2.jpg");
```

Now, my a-sky still shows "myPicture", even though the inspector shows myPicture2. Any ideas how to work around this? In my application I wish not to change the id of the asset.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having two different `img`'s and change the `src` on the entity:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="myPicture" src="myPicture.jpg">
    <img id="myPicture2" src="myPicture2.jpg">
  <a-assets>
<a-sky src="#myPicture"></a-sky>
</a-scene>

 JS: $("a-sky")[0].setAttribute("src", "#myPicture2");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

**Remove the src from Sky**

jQuery(scene).find('#' + skyId ).attr('src','');

**Update the material**

jQuery(scene).find('#' + Img360assetId).attr('src',url);

**Setting the id again**

jQuery(scene).find('#' skyId).attr('src', '#' + Img360assetId);